# System.Timers.Timer - not repeating daily on my web site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, timer

The function triggered by `timer.Elapsed` only runs once....but I want it to run every day at same time.
Any ideas?

```
static System.Timers.Timer timer;

public static void schedule_Timer()
{
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime scheduledTime = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 2, 00, 0, 0); 
    if (nowTime > scheduledTime)
    {
        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
    }

    double timeToKickoff = (double)(scheduledTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

    clsHelper.Logger("Time now is " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n....Timer set to go off " + scheduledTime + "...." + timeToKickoff + " Milliseconds", "timer");


    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeToKickoff);
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;

}
```

Comment: Every day at the same time sounds more like a cron job / scheduled task, to be honest... web apps aren't often reliably "up" for huge intervals

Comment: Since you've mentioned ASP.Net-core I've changed title to reflect that in more readable way. Please check if that edit aligns with your actual problem. Note that there are many questions "how to run repetitive tasks in ASP.Net" - you may want to [edit] post to explain how none of them gave you any idea how it should be done and why code in the question makes no sense for ASP.Net.

Comment: Not sure how you are hosting, but if you are on IIS, your web application is stopped after 20 minutes of inactivity - that's using the default settings. Consider creating your application as a Windows Service, that way it can run indefinitely ensuring your timers are always executed

Comment: Yes I already updated IIS application pool settings to get around the 20min issue

Comment: You may also have a problem if you recycle the application pool. I'm assuming that `schedule_Timer` is called everytime the application is loaded? If you do, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No I dont recycle application pool